# Get reference from ext component

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm having difficulties retrieving my input values through Extjs6's references. There doesn't seem to be a clear cut answer and google is polluted with answers that seem distinct to many different Extjs versions.

I have a window which contains a textfield and a save button, from the textfield I need to retrieve the user's input and pass it along to my ajax call.

My code:

```
window.updatePassword = function(button) {
   var win = new Ext.Window({
       referenceHolder: true,
       items: [{
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: "newPassword",
                reference: 'newPassword',
                inputType: 'password'
            }],
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'save',
            handler: function (btn) {
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: '../../Password_updatePassword.action',
                    params : {
                        newPassword: win.newPassword
                    },
                    scope: this,
                    disableCaching: true
                });
             },
             scope: this
        }]
   });
   win.show(this);
};
```

The things I've tried so far:

```
this.lookupReference('newPassword')
win.values
win.getValues()
win.newPassword
Ext.getCmp('newPassword')
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `this.lookupReference('newPassword')` - This refers to current object
  and handler dont have any component to lookup.
- `win.values` - doesnt make any sense unless you have created a config
  in win.
- `win.getValues()` - again doesnt make any sense unless you have create a method in win.
- `win.newPassword` - again same.
- `Ext.getCmp('newPassword')` - getCmp works with id, not with reference.

To get the reference of password field you can lookup on `win` object,

```
win.lookupReference('newPassword');
```

To get the value you have to use getValue() method.

```
win.lookupReference('newPassword').getValue();
```